# HTTP 302 Found - Do I need to intercept a redirect fetch for get a Token?

Tags: api, rest, request, http-status-code-302, request-headers

I'm working with a framework, on my react app, that after a first POST Login fetch where I'm sending my data, responds to me with a 302 and starts another fetch with my token into query params.
I need to intercept that token stored into the query string parameters under the key token.

So I fetch

```
/Login => I get 302 found
```

Start automatically

```
/Login/Token?token=enbrGbgr4353.....
```

The token is also into **Response Headers** of the first fetch under the key "Location" but seems it's not reachable. Should I get it on the first or second call? And in which way?

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Is this for a client-side SPA using OIDC? If so, you need to change your auth-code to use Implicit Flow or ideally, Authorization Code Flow: https://curity.io/resources/architect/oauth/spa-best-practices/#using-the-implicit-flow-for-spas - that way the OIDC token is directly accessible from client-side code.

Comment: @Dai Nope, I can use openID or Auth 2.0 but I want to use openID to prevent that final user need to do a "manual login"

Comment: What do you mean by "nope"? If this isn't an SPA then where are you running React JS? If this is for an Electron or PhoneGap app then you should update your question to provide those details.

Comment: Also **OIDC is OAuth2**, so I'm not sure why you're saying "or". And OIDC does not stop users having to login manually - it only eliminates the sign-in screen for a few scenarios which are less-and-less likely to happen with modern browsers implementing website isolation.

Comment: @Dai Sorry for the misunderstanding..mine is a client-side SPA(react) using OIDC so as you suggest I'll try to use the implicit flow

Comment: Don't use implicit flow if your program is capable of holding _secrets_ (i.e. it's a mobile _app_, as opposed to a PWA or browser-based SPA), instead use the `code` (Authorization Code) flow.

Comment: Did you solve it? How can I bring the token on the next request?